# MS Access to create XML

Tags: xml, ms-access, xsd, export

I have a sample file from a customer and need to match the schema with data from various tables in my MS Database.

Tried writing a query and exporting the XML but it oversimplifies the XML and assumes that each row from the query is a single node and all the data elements fall under each instance of that node.

Is there a way to setup a schema (possibly build it by importing my sample file) and then map fields to that for the export?

I'm open to using Excel if by chance it is better suited - just figured the access relationships would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
Sub ExportCustomerOrderData()

    Dim objOrderInfo As AdditionalData

    Dim objOrderDetailsInfo As AdditionalData



    Set objOrderInfo = Application.CreateAdditionalData



    '' Add the Orders and Order Details tables to the data to be exported.

    Set objOrderDetailsInfo = objOrderInfo.Add("Orders")

    objOrderDetailsInfo.Add "Order Details"



    '' Export the contents of the Customers table. The Orders and Order

    '' Details tables will be included in the XML file.

    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, DataSource:="Customers", _

                          DataTarget:="Customer Orders.xml", _

                          AdditionalData:=objOrderInfo

End Sub
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193212.aspx